# mapDispachToProps is giving error while firing an event onChange function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am very new to react redux. Facing some issue on onChangeHandler inside mapDispachToProps.

```
class Filterfeeds extends Component {
    checkeboxChangeHandeler = (event) => {
        console.log(this.state.viewScheduledPosts)
        let tempCheckval = !this.state.viewScheduledPosts;
        this.setState({
            viewScheduledPosts: tempCheckval
        });
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className='shaded-border-box'>
                    <TitleHeader title="Filter Feeed" style={{ paddingTop: "20px", fontSize: "18px" }} />
                    <div className="inline-items">
                        <div onChange={(e)=>this.props.onLableTribeChange(e)} style={{ marginTop: "5px", display: "flex", flexWrap: "nowrap" }}>
                            <input type="radio" name="labelTribe" defaultChecked value="label" /> Label
                            <input type="radio" name="labelTribe" style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }} value="tribe" /> Tribe
                        </div>
                        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                            <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>
                                <select className='select-box-style' name="chooseLabel" onChange={(e)=>this.props.onSelectChange(e)}>
                                    <option value='' defaultChecked>Choose Label</option>
                                    {this.props.optionsArr.map((item) => {
                                        return <option value={item} key={item}>{item}</option>
                                    })
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className='space-bet-all' style={{ marginTop: "5px", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
                                <input type='checkbox' onChange={this.checkeboxChangeHandeler} />View scheduled posts
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {this.props.labelTribe} - {this.props.chooseLabel} - 
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    // console.log('state in project', state.project)
    return {
        labelTribe:state.project.labelTribe,
        optionsArr:state.project.optionsArr,
        chooseLabel:state.project.chooseLabel
    }
}

const mapDispachToProps = (dispach) => {
    console.log(dispach);
    return {
        onLableTribeChange : (event) => dispach({ type: 'UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER', payload: event.target.value }),
        onSelectChange: (event)=> dispach({type:'SELECT_LABLE_CHANGE',payload:event.target.value}),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(Filterfeeds);
```

This is myreducer.js file below

```
const initialState = {
    optionsArr: ["my Label", "my Tribe", "your tribe", "your label"],
    labelTribe: 'label',
    chooseLabel: '',
};


const projectreducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let newstate = { ...state };
    // console.log(newstate, action)
    console.log("Action type is==>", action.type)


    switch (action.type) {
        case ('UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER'):
            newstate.labelTribe = action.payload;
            break;
        case ('SELECT_LABLE_CHANGE'):
            newstate.chooseLabel = action.payload;
            break;
        default:
            return newstate;
    }
}
export default projectreducer;
```

While I am trying to click and change the cheakboxes values, I am getting errors.

Error: Given action "UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER", reducer "project" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

This is the error i am getting.

Comment: Can you post your actions and reducers?

Comment: Just now i have edited the question. There I a have posted. If anything extra you need please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a return value in your reducer and this is way it's returning undefined. Always use return in your reducer to change the state.

```
const projectreducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let newstate = { ...state };
  // console.log(newstate, action)
  console.log('Action type is==>', action.type);

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER':
      newstate.labelTribe = action.payload;
      return newstate;
    case 'SELECT_LABLE_CHANGE':
      newstate.chooseLabel = action.payload;
      return newstate;
    default:
      return newstate;
  }
};
```

You can also simplify your code and return your new state value directly without reassigning the state. Try it like this:

```
const projectreducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('Action type is==>', action.type);

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER':
      return {
        ...state,
        labelTribe: action.payload,
      };
    case 'SELECT_LABLE_CHANGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        chooseLabel: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. But I have a doubt. Is this the best way to handle forms? Or any other best way to handle?

Comment: It's better to use component state for form handling and save data in redux on submit. Read more about forms in react documentation - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html